# Painting FocusRect with QStylePainter

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to make my own widget that uses QStyle options in order to give it a "native" look and feel.
Step 1 would be drawing a simple FocusRect, which I tried to accomplish like that:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionFocusRect()
        option.initFrom(self)
        option.backgroundColor = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background)
        painter.drawPrimitive(QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_FrameFocusRect, option)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qApp.setStyle('fusion')

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    window.widget = MyWidget(window)
    window.widget.resize(100, 100)
    window.widget.move(50, 50)

    window.setFixedSize(200, 200)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Unfortunately this only gives me an empty window. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the FrameFocusRect is only painted, when it actually has the focus.

Adding `option.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_KeyboardFocusChange` in the `paintEvent` method solves the problem.